# Python For Loop iterating X times values in list issue

Tags: python, pyodbc

```
listA = [(UK,1),(USA,2),(UAE,3)]
def fetchdata():
  base_url = 'someurl.com
  params = {countryname : country}
  resp = requests.requests('GET', base_url+params).json()

def upload():
 some sql insert code
for x in lista:
   country = listA[0]
   ID = listA[1]
   fetchdata()
   upload()
```

Above code works fine. The issue is, because there's three tuples, the SQL will upload data 3 times. If I have five tuples, it will upload data five times. I tried nested list, no luck.

My intention is such that UK will be inserted in JSON parameter, it will fetch data, assign ID/index, upload to SQL the two values. Then it will loop for next country.

What I should get is....

| Country | ID | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UK | 1 | 50 |
| US | 2 | 100 |
| UAE | 3 | 75 |

What I am getting is....

| Country | ID | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UK | 1 | 50 |
| UK | 1 | 50 |
| UK | 1 | 50 |
| US | 2 | 100 |
| US | 2 | 100 |
| US | 2 | 100 |
| UAE | 3 | 75 |
| UAE | 3 | 75 |
| UAE | 3 | 75 |

Comment: I'm sorry, can you please explain in more detail how the current execution varies from what you want to do? And please edit it your code so that it's a complete [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @CrazyChucky sorry im new. I improved it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. There was dictionary that needed to be reset before running loop again.

So...

```
values :{}
```

and during a for loop

```
for locations in locations:
  run some code
  values: {}
```

Otherwise it was rerunning SQL for previous dictionary as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
> for x in lista:
```

Did you mean listA here?

It might be iterating 5 times for each character in 'lista'